# CMake Target Link Library G++ Flags conflict with OSX Clang

Tags: linux, macos, gcc, cmake, clang

I am trying to write a single CMakeLists.txt file for C++ compilation on Linux with G++ and on OSX with Clang.

I want to use the Target Library flags `-Wl,--start-group` and `-Wl,--end-group` with G++, but these give an error when linking with Clang: `ld: unknown option: --start-group`

The only results I can find choose to just delete these flags on Mac copies, but that doesn't allow easy project migration from linux to OSX.  I tried to make these statements CMAKE conditions, but those are treated as literal libraries  which are not found:

eg:  `$<IF($<NOT:APPLE>)> -Wl,--start-group $<ENDIF($<NOT:APPLE>)>`

produces:  `c++: error: $<IF: No such file or directory`

Is there a way to conditionally edit in the CMAKE TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd try this:

```
if(${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID} STREQUAL "GNU")
    set(START_GROUP "-Wl,--start-group")
    set(END_GROUP "-Wl,--end-group")
else()
    set(START_GROUP "")
    set(END_GROUP "")
endif()
```

Then just replace those options with ${START_GROUP} and ${END_GROUP}, and they will only be used with the GNU compiler.

Don't switch based on platform if it's really the compiler that matters.  Otherwise, Clang users on Linux won't be able to build your project.